# Is it possible to access the variable from a method of a superclass in a subclass?

Tags: python

I have a parent class "Parent" that has a method "method1". This method uses a variable "b" that I want to access from the child class "Child". When I tried to access it as self.b, python complained that "'Child' object has no attribute 'b'". I am very new to object oriented programming and python. So maybe my understanding is incorrect. Please help me explain why I am unable to access 'b'.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def method1(self):
        b = 2

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child,self).__init__()
        self.vara = self.a
        self.varb = self.b

x = Child()
print x.vara
print x.varb
```

I added the "self." qualifier to variable "b" and added the same in the **init** function of the Parent class thinking that it will make it visible to the subclass.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
    def method1(self):
        self.b = 2

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child,self).__init__()
        self.vara = self.a
        self.varb = self.b

x = Child()
print x.vara
print x.varb
```

I was expecting that the output would be

```
1
2
```

because I thought self.b under method1 will overwrite self.b in the **init** function.
However, the output is

```
1
1
```

Comment: You never call `method1` so why would `self.b` ever be set to `2`?

Comment: You need to execute `method1` at some point (either in the Parent's or the Child's init, it doesn't matter) before the line `self.varb = self.b`, so that `self.b` is 2 at the time this assignment is made.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never call `method1` anywhere, so the `self.b` never gets set to value `2`.

You could just remove the whole `method1` and have the `Parent` class be like this:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

**OR**

You could call the `method1` in the `Child` class, for example:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.method1()
        self.vara = self.a
        self.varb = self.b
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that I'm missing the call to method1.

Comment: @SaravanaChandramohan No problem! Feel free to [mark this as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel like it answered your question :)